# Splash screen involving finish() and back button

Tags: android, splash-screen

Alright, so I have a splash screen on my app. I was wondering if there was a way for me to have it where it only appears the first initial time the app opens (or if they force close it and such), and so that way if they press the back key, it doesn't take them to the splash screen.

I can make it so the user cant go back to the splash screen by just typing finish() and, though I cant remember it right now, I can make it where it only loads once. Once I call finish(), the splash will reappear upon reentering the app. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Do you want your splash shows only on first run? or every time user enters the app?
finish() is correct, the splash will appear every time user uses the app, and if he goes back he will close the app without poping up the splash again.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do that by calling `finish()` on the `onPause` method of your `splashActivity`.

Or another way to do this is to add `android:noHistory="true"` on `splashActivity` of your `manifest.xml`

Answer (score 0):

With a `SplashScreenActivity` you're wasting time because they pause the initialization for 2-3seconds before they continue.

I prefer adding a `Splash Screen Layout` on top of my `main_activity.xml`. I detect the first start of the application by extending Application. If it´s the first start, I show my Splash-Screen while the UI is build in the background... (Use background threads if the ProgressBar lags!)

```
//Extend Application to save the value. You could also use getter/setter for this instead of Shared Preferences...
public class YourApplication extends Application {

    public static final String YOUR_APP_STARTUP = "APP_FIRST_START";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        //set SharedPreference value to true
        SharedPreferences mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(YOUR_APP_STARTUP, true);
        editor.apply();     
        ...    
     }
```

Check for your first start in your `MainActivity`

```
public class YourMainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //hide actionbar and other menu which could overlay the splash screen
    getActionBar().hide();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Boolean firstStart = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).getBoolean(TVApplication.YOUR_APP_STARTUP, true);

    if (firstStart) {
        //First app start, show splash screen an hide it after 5000ms
        final RelativeLayout mSplashScreen = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.splash_screen);
        mSplashScreen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mSplashScreen.setAlpha(1.0f);
        final FrameLayout mFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame_container);
        mFrame.setAlpha(0.0f);

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Animation fadeOutAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.anim.fade_out_animation);
                fadeOutAnimation.setDuration(500);
                fadeOutAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                        mFrame.setAlpha(1.0f);
                        getActionBar().show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        mSplashScreen.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                    }
                });
                mSplashScreen.startAnimation(fadeOutAnimation);
            }
        }, 5000); //<-- time of Splash Screen shown

    } else {
        ((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.splash_screen)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        getActionBar().show();
    }
```

Insert the SplashScreen at top in your main.xml. I prefer `RelativeLayout` for that. In the example, SplashScreen is placed on to of a layout with the `Navitgation Drawer`, which we really love, don`t we?

```
//main_activity.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <!-- The main content view -->

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <!-- The navigation drawer list -->

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/slider_list"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@color/tvtv_background"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@drawable/nav_bar_divider"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/splash_screen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/tvtv_white"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/splash_screen_logo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:paddingLeft="50dp"
            android:paddingRight="50dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/splash_screen_text"
            style="@style/TVTextBlueContent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/splash_screen_logo"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Awesome splash shiat" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/splash_screen_loader"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/splash_screen_text"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:indeterminate="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```